# openssl issue in laravel installation in xampp

Tags: php, windows, laravel, openssl, xampp

I am trying to install Laravel using the `Composer Windows installer` inside xampp in windows 7 . When I tried to run the composer setup after assigning the `php.exe` file location,it shows the following error.[image]

I have uncommented the `extension=php_openssl.dll`  statement from `php.ini` file(both production and development).Then also it is showing the following error. My php version is 5.4.7.

When I put the php.exe file location in one of the previous windows before the following window,it is showing the following statement:

```
Add to System path variable:
      C:\xampp\php

Add to System path variable:
      C:\ProgramData\ComposerSetup\bin
```

I have added and then removed these two variables in the `path` variable inside environment variables,then also it shows the following error.

Comment: Why dont you just use Laravel Homestead? Much easier to develop on a windows machine with it. http://laravel.com/docs/homestead

Comment: @TheShiftExchange Thanks,but can you identify what cause is showing this issue